# Oracle UPDATE updates more rows than SELECT?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query to list order number, e-mail address on order and invoice address in master data. Basically idea is that I need to update any orders not invoiced and replicate the invoice address on the order with the invoice address in master data (because it was changed since order created etc).

I wrote this SELECT which lists expected results, around 25 orders or so. I have manually verified each and this is the data that needs to be updated.

```
  select auf_adr.auf_nr, auf_adr.email, kust_adr.ku_email
     from auf_adr,auf_kopf,
          kust_adr
     where auf_adr.auf_nr = auf_kopf.auf_nr
       and auf_kopf.kunr = kust_adr.ku_nr
       and auf_adr.adr_art = 2
       and kust_adr.ku_adr_art = 1
       and auf_adr.email != kust_adr.ku_email
       and
         (select sum(auf_stat.rg_anz)
          from auf_stat
          where auf_stat.auf_nr = auf_kopf.auf_nr) = 0;
```

So great, I converted it to an UPDATE but it updates 2487385 rows! What am I doing wrong?

```
update auf_adr
  set email =
    (select kust_adr.ku_email
     from auf_kopf,
          kust_adr
     where auf_adr.auf_nr = auf_kopf.auf_nr
       and auf_kopf.kunr = kust_adr.ku_nr
       and auf_adr.adr_art = 2
       and kust_adr.ku_adr_art = 1
       and auf_adr.email != kust_adr.ku_email
       and
         (select sum(auf_stat.rg_anz)
          from auf_stat
          where auf_stat.auf_nr = auf_kopf.auf_nr) = 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you intend something like this:

```
update auf_adr
  set email = (select k.ku_email
               from auf_kopf k join
                    kust_adr ka
                    on k.kunr = ka.ku_nr
               where auf_adr.auf_nr = k.auf_nr
                     ka.ku_adr_art = 1 and
                     auf_adr.email <> ka.ku_email and
                     (select sum(s.rg_anz)
                      from auf_stat s
                      where s.auf_nr = k.auf_nr
                     ) = 0
              )
    where auf_adr.adr_art = 2 and
          exists (select 1
                  from auf_kopf k join
                       kust_adr ka
                       on k.kunr = ka.ku_nr
                  where auf_adr.auf_nr = k.auf_nr
                        ka.ku_adr_art = 1 and
                        auf_adr.email <> ka.ku_email and
                        (select sum(s.rg_anz)
                         from auf_stat s
                         where s.auf_nr = k.auf_nr
                        ) = 0
                  );
```

Comment: Thanks. I get `ERROR at line 7: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` but I don't see that there is one missing in that position?

Comment: Looks like there is one right parenthesis to many @user6888062 take a look to `where s.auf_nr = k.auf_nr) = 0 ) )` part

Comment: @GordonLinoff It was missing an `and` after `where auf_adr.auf_nr = k.auf_nr` also which I added, I think it should also be `ka.ku_email` not `k.ku_email` which I changed, but I still get `ORA-00904: "KUST_ADR"."KU_NR": invalid identifier` even though it's correct?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Appreciate any further help you can offer on this.

Answer (score 0):

if i update from select in oracle
i will use

```
update (
   select * from yourtable 
) set "yourcol" = 'yourvalue'
```

example :

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
    ("col" int, "col2" int, "col3" int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO TestTable ("col", "col2", "col3")
         VALUES (1, 2, 3)
    INTO TestTable ("col", "col2", "col3")
         VALUES (2, 3, 4)
    INTO TestTable ("col", "col2", "col3")
         VALUES (3, 4, 5)
    INTO TestTable ("col", "col2", "col3")
         VALUES (4, 5, 6)
    INTO TestTable ("col", "col2", "col3")
         VALUES (5, 6, 7)
    INTO TestTable ("col", "col2", "col3")
         VALUES (6, 7, 8)
    INTO TestTable ("col", "col2", "col3")
         VALUES (7, 8, 9)
    INTO TestTable ("col", "col2", "col3")
         VALUES (8, 9, 10)
    INTO TestTable ("col", "col2", "col3")
         VALUES (9, 10, 11)
    INTO TestTable ("col", "col2", "col3")
         VALUES (10, 11, 12)
    INTO TestTable ("col", "col2", "col3")
         VALUES (11, 12, 13)
    INTO TestTable ("col", "col2", "col3")
         VALUES (12, 13, 14)
    INTO TestTable ("col", "col2", "col3")
         VALUES (13, 14, 15)
SELECT * FROM dual
;

--Update Data
update (
  select * from TestTable
) set "col" = "col2" * 3;

select * from TestTable;
```

[image]

---

SQL Fiddle Link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/82c54/3/1

Answer (score 0):

This is because, there is no `where` condition in your update query.

Syntax of your query is:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET email = (some query);
```

This will update all the records in the table